# Data won't display Next JS

Tags: next.js

I am trying to display data from [this](https://saurav.tech/NewsAPI/top-headlines/category/technology/us.json) API.

Here is my code for displaying the data:

```
"use client";

import { SearchIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import News from './News'
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Widgets({randomUsersResults}) {

  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState()

  let displayNews;
  const URL = "https://saurav.tech/NewsAPI/top-headlines/category/technology/us.json";

  async function fetchData() {
    const newsData = await fetch(URL);
    const newsResults = await newsData.json();
    console.log(newsResults)
    displayNews = newsResults?.map(function(todo) {
      return(
        <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>
      )
    })
    setShowPosts(displayNews)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])
  

  const [articleNum, setArticleNum] = useState(3);
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl pt-2 w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
    <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">What's happening</h4>
    {showPosts}
    <button onClick={() => setArticleNum(articleNum + 3)} className="text-blue-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-blue-400">
        Show more
    </button>
</div>
```

Tt should display the data, but I am getting this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your api response .
[image]

**Mistake 1 :** As per the image `newResults` is actually an object and `newResults.articles` is actual array.

**Mistake 2:** Never save Html code in usestate variables as you did here:

```
displayNews = newsResults?.map(function(todo) {
      return(
        <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>
      )
    })
    setShowPosts(displayNews)
```

Now this code should be:

```
displayNews = newsResults.articles;
setShowPosts(displayNews)
```

And HTML code should be

```
<div className="text-gray-700 space-y-3 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl pt-2 w-[90%] xl:w-[75%]">
    <h4 className="font-bold text-xl px-4">What's happening</h4>
    {showPosts && showPosts.map((todo,index)=> <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>)}
    <button onClick={() => setArticleNum(articleNum + 3)} className="text-blue-300 pl-4 pb-3 hover:text-blue-400">
        Show more
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: but the todo function is removed. how do you invoke todo function? also item and index are declared but never used

Comment: @LeviAckerman I have updated the answer . `index` is never used but in case the item has no unique key you can use it to avoid warning. 2. The `function()` is now replaced with `()=>` (arrow function ) which is good approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your React Widgets component looks good overall. However, I noticed a few areas where the code could be improved for better performance and maintainability. I'll provide some suggestions to enhance your code:

1. **Destructure the useState Hook:**
   When using the *`useState`* Hook, it's a good practice to destructure the state variable and the setter function to improve code readability.

   `const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState();`

   `const [articleNum, setArticleNum] = useState(3);`
2. Remove Unused Import: The import statement *`useClient`* is not used in the code and can be safely removed.
3. Avoid Creating a Global Variable: Instead of using *`let displayNews`*, directly use *`const displayNews`* inside the *`fetchData function`*.
4. Utilize async/await Directly: Since *`fetchData`* is an async function, you can utilize async/await directly on the fetch and json calls to make the code cleaner and easier to understand, something like this:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const newsData = await fetch(URL);
    const newsResults = await newsData.json();
    console.log(newsResults);
    const displayNews = newsResults?.map(function (todo) {
      return (
        <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>
      );
    });
    setShowPosts(displayNews);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error, e.g., set a default state for `showPosts`
  }
}
```

5. Implement Error Handling: Handle errors that might occur during the API call. For example, you can use a try-catch block to catch and handle errors gracefully.
6. Limit the Number of Articles Displayed: Consider using the *`articleNum`* state to limit the number of articles displayed in the *displayNews* list. This way, you can control the number of articles shown without modifying the code like this:

```js
const displayedNews = newsResults?.slice(0, articleNum).map(function (todo) {
  return (
    <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>
  );
});
setShowPosts(displayedNews);
```

By incorporating these suggestions, your Widgets component will be more optimized and easier to maintain. Remember to handle errors gracefully, limit the number of articles displayed, and destructure the useState Hook for cleaner code.